# Django Cannot assign "<django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x7fc7f010ef50>": "listings.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance

Tags: python, django

I want to save an add under the current user that i'm logged in as, but i keep getting the error outlined in the subject.

My models:

```
    class CustomUser(User):
        nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        objects = UserManager()
        city = models.ForeignKey(locations, unique=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.nickname

        class Admin:
            pass

class listings(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey('category')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.naslov

    class Admin:
        pass
```

The form:

```
class jobOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=kategorii.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = listings
```

The template:

```
  <div class="span8">
    <form action="" method="POST">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
  </div>
```

The view!

```
def displisting(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = jobOfferForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            new_listng = form.save(commit = False)
            new_listng.user = request.user
            new_listng.object.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/listing/review')
    else:
        form = jobOfferForm()

    return render(request,'listings.html',{'form':form,})
```

I fear the custom user is preventing me from doing that?
But i need the extra attributes?

Comment: The `class admin` code is really out of date (pre Django 1.0 if I remember correctly). If you've just started using Django, I recommend you find a more up to date tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

this error will happen if your user is not logged in.

login  using the bundled /admin site and your request.user object will be a valid User instance

Answer (score 2):

`request.User` isn't an instance of your custom `CustomerUser`, it's a `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. Hence the assignment:

```
new_listng.user = request.user
```

isn't valid.

You probably want your request.User to be downcast to your `CustomerUser` (or other subclasses, if you have them). You can add a custom middleware, modeled off `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` that does this.

[django-model-util's `InheritanceManager`](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils#inheritancemanager) has some useful helpers like `select_subclasses` that make this easy.

Comment: Well, in my case, I have a field that is a Foreign key to `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. I get the same error `... 'Order.person' must be a `User`instance. In my `views.py`, I assign `Order.person = request.user`. Where do you think I went wrong?